# Change placeholder values to user's input

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2005, placeholder

I believe this is the correct way to go about the problem, but if there is another way please let me know.

For my report, the user enters the start date, end date, and a supplier ID.
In my report I also have four variables that are affected by the user's input. This is where the problem is, currently the date and supplier ID are hard coded in for these variables, below is an example:

```
(
    SELECT SUM( ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2 ))
    FROM IC_Products [PC] 
        INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
         ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
        INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
         ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
        INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
         ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
         ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
    WHERE  (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-04-24 00:00:00' }   AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-04-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124) ) 
  ) - @Cost
```

I know that I can add place holders such as:

```
declare @d1 datetime,
        @d2 datetime,
        @sID int;
set @d1 = 'user's input start date';
set @d2 = 'user's input end date';
set @sID = 'user's selected supplier ID';
```

And then fill in @d1, @d2, @sID in the variable's WHERE statements.

Currently the WHERE statement for the whole report looks like this:

```
WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-04-24 00:00:00' }   
    AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-04-24 00:00:00' } 
         OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate IS NULL)) 
    AND ((1=1)  
         AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (123) )
```

So when the user clicks 'Print' a dialog box pops up and they select the start date, end date, and supplier key and that is what populates the main WHERE statement, however I am not sure of how to make it correlate to the WHERE statements in my variables.

I am using Microsoft SQL 2005, and no other languages besides SQL. However, this is a software that has prebuilt functions and a GUI where the user inputs the information.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Full Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Shrink Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Cost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Profit Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Proj Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
);
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;
SET @Cost  = ROUND((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
), 2);
SET @Profit  = (
 SELECT SUM(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2))
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
) - @Cost;
SET @Proj  = ROUND((@Profit) / (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
), 2)
;

SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , @Shrink AS [Shrink]
   , @Cost AS [Cost]
   , @Profit AS [Profit]
   , @Proj AS [Proj]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 **WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124) )** 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

The WHERE code surrounded by ** is the code that is populated by the user input, the other WHERE codes are hard coded, but I need the hard coded ones to change to the main WHERE code.

Comment: Are you using SSRS for your reporting?

Comment: @LDMJoe I don't believe so, how would I figure this out? The software I am running is called Canopy, http://aspen-systems.com/solutions/canopy-core-system/overview

Comment: any luck on this? Just curious if you figured out what was wrong?

Comment: @Dasman yeah, I ended up not making the mathematical functions variables and just did them as standard expressions so then I wouldn't have to worry about the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= @d1  
    AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= @d2
         OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate IS NULL)) 
    AND ( AR_Customers.CustomerKey =@sID )
```

Sounds like all you need to do is place those variables in your where clause instead of the literals you were using.

Comment: if I replace those in the WHERE section for each variable it would still not populate with the user's input. I provided my full code above if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you declare the variables BEFORE the Where clause - the variables can be put into the where clause:

Sample from Source:

```
DECLARE @EmpIDVar INT

SET @EmpIDVar = 1234

SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpIDVar
```

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212846(v=sql.80).aspx

Good Luck!

Comment: the problem is that EmpIDVar would have to be set by whatever the user inputs, not by me.

Comment: Will the user work with your query? Then he can just change the SET field to whatever he wants. If the user wants a GUI(Graphical User Interface) thats not possible through SQL(as far as I know). you'd need Mysql or Java for that. SQL is backend.

Comment: currently the user runs the report on a GUI, and it "sets" the WHERE statement, it just doesn't set the WHERE statements inside of the variables. I added my full code to the main question. Does that change anything?

Comment: Wait there is a GUI? Then all you need is textbox to take the input store it as a variable and use it in SQL. How does the GUI work that the user uses? Which technology?

Comment: Yeah, well I edit some SQL and then other stuff is pre-built into the system that generates the proper SQL code. For the users, they select the report I created and then a dialog box appears with a field for them to select the start date and end date as well as the supplier ID. The program is called Canopy by Aspen Systems.

Comment: I had an idea. It may be too naive, but since its managed by Canopy any chance you can contact their IT? I'm sure they can modify their form to allow for a variable passthrough and a user prompt.